# Is there a particular scipy/opencv/other function which computes 3 "center points" of a roughly crescent binary mask?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, scipy, pytorch

I'd like to compute three "center points" of a crescent-shaped binary blob in Python as shown below:

[sample_desired_output_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22CN8.png)

The desired function output should be the three red points shown in the sketch, which can be imagined to lie along the approximate "center curve" of the crescent binary mask. The two end points should be approximately the "centroids" of the two tips of the crescent whereas the central point should approximately lie in the middle of the "center curve".

Any suggestions and advice is welcome!

Comment: You want the skeleton or thinning operation after thresholding. See https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/edges/plot_skeleton.html

Comment: Thanks, will take a look